# Open Silverlight web resource from a button in Navigation

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I need to a add a button to the navigation or ribbon area of the CRM 2015 on-premise. This button should open an existing Silverlight web resource. Is that possible ?

EDIT:

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328498.aspx) MSDN article mentions that the URL holds a value of a URL or an HTML web resource, does that mean that Silverlight webresource is not possible ?

> Url
>   Specifies a URL or HTML Web Resource for a page to display in the main frame of the application when this subarea is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a page to host the Silverlight control, as specified [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309473.aspx):

> To display a Silverlight web resource outside an entity form or chart,
>   create an HTML web resource to be the host page for the Silverlight
>   web resource. Then use the $webresource: directive to open the HTML
>   web resource.

Once it is created, make sure you reference the page web resource in your site map/ribbon.

There is a good tutorial [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/01/19/building-multi-purpose-silverlight-web-resources-in-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx) on how to set that up.